# text getting overwritten in output file

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

```
from urllib import request
from redditscore.tokenizer import CrazyTokenizer
tokenizer = CrazyTokenizer()
url = "http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi5386/A1_2020/microblog2011.txt"
for line in request.urlopen(url):
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(line.decode('utf-8'))
    #print(tokens)
with open('your_file.txt', 'a') as f:
    print(tokens)
    for item in tokens:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

In the above code my output is in the form of list in variable tokens. When i'm trying to print my output to a file, text is getting overwritten. I'm only getting last line of my output

please help..

Comment: What are you getting in tokens ? As per code it should be the last token read from that file. Is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of `tokens` every time loop runs in below part so it's overwriting

```
for line in request.urlopen(url):
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

so better append the tokens in the list

```
from urllib import request
from redditscore.tokenizer import CrazyTokenizer
tokenizer = CrazyTokenizer()
url = "http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi5386/A1_2020/microblog2011.txt"

tokens = []
for line in request.urlopen(url):
    tokens.extend(tokenizer.tokenize(line.decode('utf-8')))
    #print(tokens)

with open('your_file.txt', 'a') as f:
    print(tokens)
    for item in tokens:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```